# File upload error Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string this error come when i run my code

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $file_ex=$request -> photo -> getClientOriginalExtension();

    $file_name = $file_ex.time();

    $path ='/images/users';
    
    $request -> photo ->move($path, $file_name);
```

where the problem

file uploade , find out why this not working

Comment: do you tried `$file_ex = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();`

Comment: yeah the error is gone but the photo not move to the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Okay, this is the answer, or what I made to solve this issue.

At first, make sure of 3 things:

1. Make sure that your form works with files.

in `enctype="multipart/form-data"` put it on form #tag like:

```
<form action="{{url('store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

2. Make sure that your function in your controller works fine, like

> ```
> $file = $request->photo;
> $file_ex =$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
> $filename = time().rand(1,99).'.'.$file_ex;
> $path ='images/users';
> $file->move(public_path($path),$filename);
> ```

Okay, this works fine.

3. Handling our file system

go to `config/filesystems.php`

and scroll down until you will find  `'disks' => [`

In disks, you will find 'local' , 'public', and 's3' copy public and paste it on side 'public' and make some changes like:

At first, we will see

public :

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],
```

1. Change the root, like `'root' => base_path().'/public/images/users',` or you can put which path you want.

2: change the url, like `'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',` or you can specify which URL you want.
 
The code will be:

```
'users' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => base_path().'/public/images/users',
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
    'visibility' => 'public',
    'throw' => false,
],
```

Thank you for your assistance,
If there are any issues, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try like this,

```
    $file = $request->file('photo');
    $file_ex = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filename = time().rand(1,99).'.'.$file_ex;
    $path ='images/users';

    $file->move(public_path($path),$filename);
```

Comment: it's okay no errors but when i open the path nothing is there

Answer (score 1):

first run this command to generate symbolic link

```bash
php artisan storage:link
```

then in controller function

```php
$fileTemp = $request->file('file');
if($fileTemp->isValid()){
  $fileExtension = $fileTemp->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $fileName = Str::random(4). '.'. $fileExtension;
  $path = $fileTemp->storeAs(
    'public/documents', $fileName
  );
}
```

above code will save your file in `storage/app/public/documents` location
and using symbolic link we can access this file here `public/storage/documents`

> read [file-uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-uploads) full docs in laravel official docs

Comment: thnx bro but i solve it